# Is there a function to check if a folder name is the same as current date?

Tags: powershell, directory, names

I would  need help to write a powershell script that checks if there is a folder with the same name as the current date (ddmmyyyy).
The script would run every day and copy all files from that folder into another overwriting everything.

I have searched in google but could find no examples

I expect the script to check the subfolders of the current folder and select the one that has the same name as the current date, than go in that folder and copy the files to another location.

Comment: Google is full of examples of this, I really think foundation learning and understanding is needed on your part before asking for help. If you already have something that is currently giving you a specific issue or error, please update your question to include it :)

Comment: Hi, I agree with you and this is what I always do, google the heck out of it, but I really could not find any pointers in this case

Comment: There is enough information about this on Google. As a simple tip: look for a way to get the current date in the required format (so lookup the documentation on Get-Date), then test if a folder with that name exists using Test-Path (so again, lookup the documentation on this cmdlet). I am happy to help you with your code but I won't write it for you.

Comment: @bluuf : you are right folks, I do not have knowledge of Powershell at all and so far I somehow managed just copying things on Google. I should actually go and study it a bit more. Thank you for the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a basic script that checks if the folder with the current date exists.

```
$folderPath = "c:\myRootFolder"
$date = Get-Date
$dateString = $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

$doesexist = Test-Path ($folderPath + "\" + $dateString)

if($doesexist){
    Write-Host "folder does Exist"
}else{
    Write-Host "Folder does not exits"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am working on your code to solve 1 problem: <Test-Path ($folderPath + "\" + $dateString)> returns "False" even if the folder is there, The issue is  with $datestring, it is not recognised on the Test-Path

Comment: The correct syntax was yyyyMMdd and also I had to put a <\*>  after $ datestring to copy all the items in the subfolder.

Comment: It now works perfectly and it was a HUGE help for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

````
#$date = Get-Date
$dateString = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"

$doesexist = Test-Path ($folderPath + "\" + $dateString)

if($doesexist){
    Copy-Item -Force ($folderPath + "\" + $dateString + "\*") -Destination $folderPath
}else{
    Write-Host "Folder does not exits"
}```
````